# Android Firebase Login - No Errors but doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

EDIT: I added a Toast with task.getException() and got:
Authentication failed: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly formatted.
But I typed in the email address that I added to the Firebase DB (test@testuser.com)

I am working on an Android app that uses a Login feature. I am implementing Firebase. I am using the following tutorial: http://www.amalhichri.net/android-getting-started-with-firebase-user-authentication/

I see no glaring errors in the Android Monitor, yet when I run the app on my phone, type in a username & password, I just get the toast message that it is incorrect (which only runs if this is hit:

```
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
   if (!task.isSuccessful()) )
```

There are no errors running it that show in Android Monitor. There is a warning in my Java file that says: 
    "*unchecked assignment: anonymous 
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener to com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener '<'com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult'>'*"

I have done the following:

- I have added a user with a password at my
  console.firebase.google.com
- Created the Main Activity in UI and Java
- Attempted to update all my SDK's
- Attempted to update my Manifest
- Attempted to update my Gradles
- Attempted using Googles tutorial, as well as a few others

Android Monitor:

- W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
- I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
- I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
- W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
- I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 7
- W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
- (Only thing that was red): 11-01 16:42:00.193 20389-20389/com.netgalaxystudios.timeclock E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]

Java Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    //private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private Button btnSignIn;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UsernameET);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordET);

        TextView registerNowTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterNowTV);

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginBTN);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login failed! Invalid email or password,\nPlease try agin.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                                else {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                                    finish();

                                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my gradle from the app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //compileSdkVersion 25
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.appname"
        minSdkVersion 23
        //targetSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.27.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Modify your toast or add a log-statement to output the value of `email`.  Also, to be safe you should trim the entered strings, e.g.: `email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim()`.

Comment: Also the check your layout XML for the `UsernameET` [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)  to confirm that you are using an appropriate input type.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139472/4815718

Comment: Thanks Bob Snyder I used both of your suggestions. The first helped me get over the problem of this question, and the second made my app better!

Comment: already answered here have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/62280301/13699785